# how to ajust the place of rectangle using java

Tags: java, rectangles

how to auto adjust the place of rectangle ?
for example i have 5 rect

here my code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class gambar
{
    JFrame fr=new JFrame("exampe");
    JScrollPane sc;
    int hight,weight;
    JTabbedPane tab=new JTabbedPane();
    gambar()
    {   
        int[]x=new int[5];
        int[]y=new int[5];
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setLocation(0,0);
        fr.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        fr.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        tab.addTab("Panel1",new panel1());
        fr.add(tab);    
        fr.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new gambar();
    }
}
class panel1 extends JPanel
{
    panel1()
    {
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g3)
    {
        int x=0,y=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            if(i==1)
            {   x=50;y=50;  }
            else if(i==2)
            {   x=300;y=50; }
            else if(i==3)
            {   x=50;y=200; }
            else if(i==4)
            {   x=300;y=200;}
            else if(i==5)
            {   x=175;y=125;    }
            g3.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g3.fillRect(x,y,90,30);
            g3.setColor(Color.black);
            g3.drawString("square "+i,x+5,y+15);
        }
    }
}
```

the output is here :

[image: rectangle five]

if i have 4 rect, output like here

[image: rectangle four]

if 3 rect, output like here

[image: rectangle three]

i have no idea how to auto ajust the place without set coordinate.
sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

It's all basic geometry. Write it out on paper.

Assume that the sides of the area are called `w` and `h`, then you can easily calculate the center of each rectangle. From the center you subtract half the rectangle's width to get it's leftedge x coordinate, and half the height the get its top-edge y coordinate, etc.
If you want to keep some space around it, you first subtract that space from the `w` and the `h` above, and you add half that space to each x and y coordinate of each of the rectangles.

### for 5 rectangles

```
x1 = 0 + rectangle_width/2, y1 = 0 + rectangle_height / 2
x2 = w - rectangle_width/2, y2 = 0 + rectangle_height / 2
x3 = w / 2, y3 = h / 2
x4 = 0 + rectangle_width/2, y4 = h - rectangle_height / 2
x5 = w - rectangle_width/2, y5 = h - rectangle_height / 2
```

### for 4 rectangles

```
x1 = 0 + rectangle_width/2, y1 = 0 + rectangle_height / 2
x2 = w - rectangle_width/2, y2 = 0 + rectangle_height / 2
x3 = 0 + rectangle_width/2, y3 = h - rectangle_height / 2
x4 = w - rectangle_width/2, y4 = h - rectangle_height / 2
```

### for 3 rectangles

```
x1 = 0 + rectangle_width/2, y1 = 0 + rectangle_height / 2
x2 = w - rectangle_width/2, y2 = 0 + rectangle_height / 2
x3 = w / 2, y2 = h - rectangle_height / 2
```

Comment: That depends on how you want to lay them out. There are unlimited different ways in which you could do so.